# How to run a php file(websocket server) in background into web server(www.example.com)

Tags: php

I have downloaded a websocket example and tested with xamp server locally and it is working fine. It has a php file called sever.php which i have to run it from the command prompt first to run the server. After that i can able to connect to the websocket server and can send message. Everything is running fine with my laptop. Now I have uploaded the same project to my web server (lets say www.example.com).
Since without running the server.php the client can not able to connect to the server, so how can i run the server.php in background into web server.
After search in the forum i found a function which can run php file in background as below.

```
$cmd='nohup php php-socket.php >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
function execInBackground($cmd){ 
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
} 
else { 
    exec($cmd);
    //echo 'command executed';   
} }
```

From the index file i called this function to running the server but not work.
Is it this function able to run? If so from where i should call this function?

In the console i am getting the following error.

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8090/dmp/chat_websocket/php-socket.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>   (anonymous) @ (index):25

Highly appreciated if someone help me in this regards.

Comment: Since yesterday viewed 16 times but nobody answer!!!!. Apart from million of experts, does anyone can answer my questions? Please...

Comment: have same needs , do you have any news ?

Answer (score 2):

After 2 years, 8 months no one have added a solution.

I have no solution for you too :). But I thing you need access to the command Line from your server and for sure is not the best thing your provider will give you access to it.

You miss something in your example is to call the function **execInBackground($cmd)**

```php
$cmd='nohup PHP php-socket.php >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!';
function execInBackground($cmd){ 
 if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
 } 
 else { 
    exec($cmd);
    //echo 'command executed';   
 } 
}
```

**Add this at the end:**

```php
execInBackground($cmd);
```

**edit:**
I make some test.
I added this in the top of the page (example server.php)

```php
/* Remove the execution time limit */
ini_set("max_execution_time", "0");
ini_set("max_input_time", "0");
set_time_limit(0);
```

Make sure you have something in place to stop it.

After just call your script in the browser ([www.example.com/server.php](http://www.example.com/server.php))
it will run forever just close the tab. Your websocket script should not stop running.